# HTML form to load points on Google Maps using API?

Tags: google-maps-api, php

I am creating a web page with a Google Map embedded in it.  I want to create a form to allow a user to type which London tube zone they wish to see and, when submitted, this will map the tube stations for the selected zone.

I have the map embedded where I want it to be and centred with the zoom I need.  I can hard code the map to display one of the zones using:

```
downloadUrl("ldntube_xml.php?zone=1", function(data) {
```

But I want the user to be able to select the zone they want.

For the form so far I have:

```
<form action="ldntube_xml.php" method="get">
    Type Zone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="zone" value="" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This obviously takes the user away from the web page to list the stations in the zone selected.

How can I make the form and the map display talk to each other?
Can I accomplish this using an onClick"myFunction()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX. In jQuery style, something like this should do what you are tryingto accomplish:

```
<form>
    Type Zone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="zone" id="zone"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn-tubline-submit"/>
</form>

<script>
  $("#btn-tubeline-submit").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedLine = $("#zone").val();
    if(selectedLine.length>0){
        $.get("ldntube_xml.php", {"zone": selectedLine}).done(function(data){
            /*data will be the response from your php script here containing the stops that you want to display on the map*/
        });
    }
  });
</script>
```